# Cufon IE Invalid Argument

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cufon, invalid-argument

Okay, I'm a little stumped with this one. I am usng Cufon to replace my text with a non-web standard font. This is a script I've used an aweful lot & never had a problem with it in the past. Along comes IE and it decides to ruin my day.

I am using the most up to date version of cufon (as at the date of this post) and am reference a number of differnt elements in my *header.php* file (for a Wordpress site):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >Cufon.replace('.learnmore', { color: '#fff', textShadow: '1px 1px #0e1b0a', hover: { textShadow: '1px 1px #000',  color: '#fff'   }   });     </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >Cufon.replace('.logo span, h1, h2, h4 , h5, h6, .learnmore, .prosto_button, .comment-reply-link, .slide_button, .page_title .bold p, .textonlycont, .h-title', { fontFamily: "Aller"});   </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >Cufon.replace('.h-title', { textShadow: '1px 2px #5C1003' });     </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >Cufon.replace('h1', { color: '-linear-gradient(white, #ececec)', textShadow: '#862905 0 2px'});   </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/pondera/js/cufon/Vegur.font.js?ver=1.0.0'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >Cufon.replace('h3, #serv-benefit h4, p.quote, #letstalk label', { fontFamily: "Vegur"});  </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >Cufon.replace('#letstalk label', { fontFamily: "Vegur", textShadow: '1px 2px #293719' }); </script>
```

Not sure if this is the best way to reference multiple different fonts but it's working fine in all browsers bar IE (specifially **v.8.0.7** which I'm currently running). IE gives the following error report:

> Webpage error details:
>
> Message: Invalid argument.
>   Line: 7
>   Char: 8520
>   Code: 0
>   URI: http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/pondera/js/cufon/cufon-yui.js?ver=1.0.0

I investigated the Cufon js file and this appears to be just before a `D.replaceChild` reference. Now I am far from a JS expert so I have no idea what is causing this problem...

Just for reference, by way of a test, I attempted to remove all bar the first `Cufon.replace(...` reference (i.e. the above code) to see if it was my poor coding but this didn't fix it.

**Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!** Thanks in advance for readaing this, I'd be happy to provide more info should it be required.

Comment: btw there is another font js reference above the code I posted, looks like i missed it when copying & pasting!

Comment: Why all of those script tags? All of those `Cufon` lines can be inside one `<script></script>` element.

Comment: Can you make cufon-yui.js available somewhere to look at?

Comment: @epascarello - ummm, i have no good answer to that... I will fix asap!

I have literally just copied the code as per: http://cufon.shoqolate.com/js/cufon-yui.js?v=1.09i

...and the error still exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I have found a soultion (of sorts)... and possibly a bug in Cufon itself (although I wouldn't be surprised if I was wrong!).

As Epascarello suggested, I'm proved the layout of my code to fewer script tags:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
        Cufon.replace('.logo span, h1, h2, h5, h6, .learnmore, .prosto_button, .comment-reply-link, .slide_button, .page_title .bold p, .textonlycont, .h-title', { fontFamily: "Aller"});
        Cufon.replace('h1', { color: '-linear-gradient(white, #ececec)', textShadow: '#862905 0 2px'});
        Cufon.replace('.learnmore', {   color: '#fff', textShadow: '1px 1px #0e1b0a', hover: { textShadow: '1px 1px #000',  color: '#fff'   }});
        Cufon.replace('.h-title', { textShadow: '1px 2px #5C1003' });
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/pondera/js/cufon/Vegur.font.js?ver=1.0.0'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
        Cufon.replace('h3, #serv-benefit h4, p.quote, #letstalk label', { fontFamily: "Vegur"});
        Cufon.replace('#letstalk label', { fontFamily: "Vegur", textShadow: '1px 2px #293719' });
    </script>
```

Whilst doing this I took some time to sequentially test the code as it was inserted to see when the error occured. During this I tested each selector & all worked bar one... **h4**!?!? To clarify if you amend the first linein the code above to the following, the IE error will occur:

```
        Cufon.replace('.logo span, h1, h2, h4, h5, h6, .learnmore, .prosto_button, .comment-reply-link, .slide_button, .page_title .bold p, .textonlycont, .h-title', { fontFamily: "Aller"});
```

Weird huh?! The soultion I'm using is to amend my markup to  avoid the H4 tags but presumably this is an error in Cufon?

Hope this helps someone!